# How do I recompile apache in CentOS?

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, centos5, pcre

I need to recompile apache with an external PCRE library. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can't just preload it why?

Answer (score 3):

1. delete existing apache but keep configs
2. download the source
3. untar it
4. compile it with that special module

Comment: +1 But may I suggest using `yum` to remove Apache rather than just deleting the binaries in step one?